# properly map to webapp to domain in tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat7

Somehow I cannot normally map domain to my webapp in tomcat7.

Here is the parts from server.xml:

```
 <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

 <Host name="mydomain.com" appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true">
        <Alias>www.mydomain.com</Alias>
        <Context path="" docBase="myapp"/>
                    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
                    pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false" />
    </Host>
```

Does the defaultHost must be localhost or mydomain.com?

I have written a script which deploys myapp in ubuntu:

```
#!/bin/bash
service tomcat7 stop
rm -rf /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/myapp/
cp myapp.war /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/
service tomcat7 start
```

After running this script I can access my app only like this: mydomain.com/myapp

If I restart tomcat then it maps to the domain ok, but there is two webapps running.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To make your web application the default webapp you can simply

- rename your myapp.war to ROOT.war,
- rm -r /usr/share/tomcat/webappas/ROOT
- cp ROOT.war /usr/share/tomcat/webapps

more information available at: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application.3F

Comment: Well this helps, but only because I have only one webapp.

Comment: Well on production machines, I'm running one tomcat instance per webapp. This makes monitoring easier